# Makefile which only forwards to subdirectories

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile, which should when calling `make` just call `make` in a list of subdirectories. The subdirectories should not be automatically detected but are fine to be hard coded (`Tool1`, `Package2`, `Submodule3` below). Furthermore, if I call `make Tool1`, `Tool1` should be built (i.e. the directory names should be recognised as targets).
At this top level I have no use for dependency checking, the `Makefile`s in the subdirectories take care of that. My current version looks like this:

```
subdirs := Tool1 Package2 Submodule3

.PHONY: all clean $(subdirs)

all:

clean:

define makesubdir
$(1):
  make -C $(1)

all: $(1)
endef

define makesubdirclean
$(1)-clean:
  make -C $(1) clean

clean: $(1)-clean
endef

$(foreach SUBDIR,$(subdirs),$(eval $(call makesubdir,$(SUBDIR))))
$(foreach SUBDIR,$(subdirs),$(eval $(call makesubdirclean,$(SUBDIR))))
```

What I already considered:

- I don't want a for loop in the `all` target, to allow parallel building with `make -j`. An older version read like:

  all:
     for DIR in $(subdirs); do make -C $$DIR ; done
- The subdirectories should be defined only in one place, adding a new subdirectory should happen only on one place.
- The subdirectories are `.PHONY` such that `make` gets called in them, regardless of the directory's timestamp.
- I thought `all: $(subdirs)` would be easier to read than `all: $(1)` but that way only `Tool1` got built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a matter of personal taste, but I use functions as the last resort. Consider

```
.PHONY: $(subdirs)

all: $(subdirs)
clean: $(subdirs)

$(subdirs):
    make -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```